# How to use npm config variables of package.json in npm scripts

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

I have a npm project which I'm using many flags when calling node.js, so my package.json scripts are a little confusing, like this:

```
"scripts": {
        "test": "node --use_strict -r dotenv/config --experimental-vm-modules node_modules/.bin/jest",
        "testwatch": "node --use_strict -r dotenv/config --experimental-vm-modules node_modules/.bin/jest -watchAll",
        "start": "node --use_strict -r dotenv/config --experimental-vm-modules ./src/index"
    },
```

Is there a way to specify the node.js flags in a single parameter in the package.json file so that it is passed to all scripts simultaneously? Or if you can give me another suggestion to make these commands more organized it would be useful too. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I can only think of two solutions for this problem.

1. Using package.json config variable
2. Using an alias

### Solution 1:

You can access config variables in the scripts by `$npm_package_config_<variable-name>`

`package.json` file

```json
"config": {
    "testflags": "--use_strict -r dotenv/config --experimental-vm-modules"
},
"scripts": {
    "test": "node $npm_package_config_testflags node_modules/.bin/jest"
}
```

### Solution 2:

> By the way I don't know How to do this on windows machine!!! So I'm assuming you're using Mac or GNU/Linux OS.

Create an alias in your shellrc file (e.g., `~/.bashrc` for bash and `~/.zshrc` for zsh etc.).

Add the following in your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc` file or whatever shellrc file you have.

```
alias node_test='node --use_strict -r dotenv/config --experimental-vm-modules'
```

**Note:** Here you've to provide the full path of the `dotev/config` file. To get full path of the `config.js` file go to the `dotenv` directory and run `readlink -f config`. Copy the full path of file and replace `dotenv/config` in the above alias.

Then save the file and source it by running `source ~/.bashrc` in the terminal.

Now in your package.json file:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "node_test node_modules/.bin/jest"
}
```

Comment: Was something exactly like solution 1 that I was looking for. Thanks.