# How do I properly pass a variable in npm?

Tags: node.js, variables, npm

I am trying to pass a variable in npm per Solution 1 here [How to use npm config variables of package.json in npm scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69234337/how-to-use-npm-config-variables-of-package-json-in-npm-scripts) but cannot seem to get it right. I have tried several variations of the below code to no avail. Can someone tell me the right way to do it?

UPDATE:

I had actually started from a point closer to that mentioned by xehpuk (below) but I cannot retrieve the variable from there either.  I have updated the code below to reflect that

SOLUTION:
This works!

test.js

```
const main = function () {
  console.log(process.argv)
}

main()
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "testing",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "config": {
    "params": "{\"height\": 33, \"width\": 22}]"
  },
  "license": "",
  "scripts": {
  "return": "node test.js --params=$npm_package_config_params"  
  }
}
```

result

```
[
  '/home/dcode/.nvm/versions/node/v18.3.0/bin/node',
  '/mnt/d/bin/tools/test.js',
  '--params={"height":',
  '33,',
  '"width":',
  '22}]'
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access it via `process.env.npm_package_config_params`.

[package.json > config | npm Docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#config)

`process.argv` works for me with:

```json
{
    "config": {
      "params": "{\"height\": 33, \"width\": 22}]"
    },
    "scripts": {
      "return": "node test.js \"$npm_package_config_params\""
    }
}
```

Result:

```
$ npm run return

> test@0.1.0 return
> node test.js "$npm_package_config_params"

[
  '/usr/bin/node',
  '/home/xehpuk/test.js',
  '{"height": 33, "width": 22}]'
]
```

Comment: Thank you. I had actually started from that point but cannot retrieve the variable.  I have edited the code above to reflect.

Answer (score 0):

A working solution is posted above!